# Sharepoint Library site detection

Tags: sharepoint, list

When I go to a page in sharepoint portal.
How to detect that is library page or list (not calendar or task ...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
SPList list = SPContext.Current.List;
if (list.BaseTemplate == SPListTemplateType.DocumentLibrary || 
    list.BaseTemplate == SPListTemplateType.GenericList)
{
    // Current Page is associated with a Document Library or Custom List
}
```